# C++ program crashes at delete only when character array gets the input of "1000!"

Tags: c++

I wrote a quick and dirty factorial program using the GMP library in C++, which allocates some memory for a character array. The program works fine for all input values that I've tested, except 1000.

I've tried different ways to allocate the memory, and different ways to deallocate it, but none have worked so far and almost always crash on 1000.

This is everything that happens between creating the character array and deleting it. `factor` is the calculated factorial and `mpz_sizeinbase` returns the number of digits in the number in the specified base. `gmp_sprintf` just transforms the number into the character array.

```cpp
int count = mpz_sizeinbase(factor, 10);
    char* zeroes = new char[count];

    gmp_sprintf(zeroes, "%Zd", factor);

    printf("After conversion: %s\n", zeroes);

    int trailingzeroes = 0;
    for(int i = strlen(zeroes)-1; i > 0; i--){
        if(zeroes[i] == '0')
            trailingzeroes++;
        else
            break;
    }

    printf("Trailing zeroes: %i\n", trailingzeroes);


    delete [] zeroes;
```

When the input is 1000, meaning that I want to calculate 1000!, I get the error

```
double free or corruption (!prev)
Aborted
```

at `delete []`.
All other inputs work, as far as I can tell.
What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please post the code for `mpz_sizeinbase`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, not a function that I am familiar with, I thought it was the OP's code.

Comment: @LordWilmore It's a function in the GMP library. https://gmplib.org/manual/Miscellaneous-Integer-Functions.html#Miscellaneous-Integer-Functions

Comment: Sounds like the lack of the null terminator causing delete to access illegal memory.

Comment: Document at https://gmplib.org/manual/Miscellaneous-Integer-Functions.html suggests,  The right amount of allocation is normally two more than the value returned by mpz_sizeinbase, one extra for a minus sign and one for the null-terminator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`mpz_sizeinbase` documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Miscellaneous-Integer-Functions.html): *"The right amount of allocation is normally **two more** than the value returned by `mpz_sizeinbase`, one extra for a minus sign and **one for the null-terminator**."* You probably don't have a negative factorial, but you are certainly not allocating enough space for including the terminating null character.

It would be instructive to check the return value of [`gmp_sprintf`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Formatted-Output-Functions.html) because it tells you how many characters it actually wrote. I would wager that in your case it returns `count+1`, which would mean it wrote past the end of the buffer (which is Undefined Behavior).

The fact that it sometimes might work is probably related to the fact that *"the result will be either exact or 1 too big"* (for bases other than 2). That and of course the unpredictable nature of UB.

Comment: The exception is thrown at the delete operator. What would be the reason for that?

Comment: @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth Undefined behavior is undefined behavior. It could also format your hard drive for all you know. Whatever came after the allocated array (for example, the control block of the next allocation...) just got blown to bits by a null character, so the fact that some allocation list is now broken (which is what `!prev` in the assertion sounds like) would make sense. But don't try to reason too hard about it - be happy that it failed in some observable way reasonably close to the origin.

Comment: As in why is the delete behaviour undefined? Is it the lack of the null terminator? OP states that the program throws at the delete keyword and not at `gmp_sprintf` I'm trying to figure out why

Comment: @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth Writing past the end of an array is UB. Once your program has any UB, its **entire** behavior (including anything before and after the operation) is no longer determined by the standard. Recommended reading: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633